# When my model is exported to gltf, the model is deformed. What is the problem?

Tags: gltf

[image]

[image]

It looks like the body of the dish has stretched and the bracket is normal.

Looking forward to and thanks for your answer~

Comment: I don't know much about export formats, but did you apply the scale to your dish before exporting (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode)?